# Compact-open topology and Krull topology on Galois groups

Tags: general-topology, galois-theory

Let $E/F$ be a Galois extension and consider $E$ as a discrete topological space. Denote $G^{KO} = \operatorname{Gal}(E/F)^{KO}$ the Galois group endowed with the Compact-open topology in $\operatorname{Map}(E,E)$ (continuous functions). That is, the coarsest topology such that the sets
$$C(K,U) = \{f:E \to E\;|\; f(K) \subseteq U\},$$
where $K$ is compact and $U$ is open, are open.

I want to show that this topology coincides with the Krull topology on $G$.
It suffices to show that the identity
$$G \to G^{KO}$$
is continuous, since $G^{KO}$ is hausdorff and $G$ is compact. I've already reduced this to showing that the sets $C(\{\alpha\}, \{w\})$ are open in $G$, where $\alpha , w \in E$ are arbitrary. However this is the part where I'm stuck. If I'm not mistaken, we need to show that any $\sigma \in C(\{\alpha\}, \{w\}) \cap G$ is contained in an open neighborhood of $G$, i.e. in some $\operatorname{Gal}(E/M)$ where $M/F$ is a finite extension. How exactly can we do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The basic open sets of $G$ are not just those of the form $\Gal(E/M$ with $M/F$ finite. You also have to consider all translates of these.